# Recognize only one gesture at a time

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, gesture

I need to recognise only one gesture at a time in my app.
Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
return NO;
}
```